# How to disable default shipping and payment options on checkout with WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to disable the default payment option and shipping option on the "view cart" and/or "checkout" pages on WooCommerce.

Everything I have tried did not work. JS is failing since this section is keeping refreshed. and PHP fails since it refreshes unselected on every change in the cart.

Any idea of how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to disable the default selection?

Comment: We had too many cases where clients did not actually put a thought on it, and hit the Continue button. It made some difficulties after that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_default_gateway' . '__return_false', 99 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', '__return_false', 99);
```

This does only remove the default selection. If the selection is stored in your session it will be applied as normal. Keep that in mind when testing.

Edit: Unfortunately, since WooCommerce 4+ this does not work anymore.

Comment: why not use `remove_filter ` instead?

Comment: @jycr753: remove_filter would just revert to the default, which is what he wants to change.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Thanks. It is working... partly. Although the defaults are not set at the begining, once the user select a shipping method, the payment method also is set. My other approach was to work with cookies and ajax... it worked, but honestly I do prefer this solution than something unstable as I did. Thanks!

Comment: `pre_option_woocommerce_default_gateway` no longer appears to be working. I've scanned the codex but cannot find a _new_ implementation of this. Any ideas @Pelmered?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what the best way to do that is now when the filter is removed. Maybe you can just reset the chosen methods in the users session like this in an appropriate place in your code(you only want to run this once before the checkout is loaded the first time as it will reset the selection after the customer have made otherwise):
`WC()->session->set( 'chosen_payment_method', '' );` and 
`WC()->session->set( 'chosen_shipping_methods', '' );`

Comment: doing `WC()->session->set( 'chosen_payment_method', '' );`will select the first payment method on woocommerce by default, so it is not a solution. and `pre_option_woocommerce_default_gateway` doesn't work anymore in latest versions of woocommerce 4.x

Comment: I tried your default gateway filter, it doesn't work anymore (per Feb 2021)

Comment: @AlphaX I guess the best is to just set the gateway you want to be selected by default in the session.

Comment: `pre_option_woocommerce_default_gateway` may no longer work but I want to clarify that `woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method`still does as of July 2021